# Display Sidebar On Woocommerce Category Page

Tags: php, woocommerce

My category page is currently putting the sidebar below the products:
http://www.ontario-wine.com/product-category/white-wine/

This page uses Woocommerce's templates. How do I get that side bar (called 'Regular Sidebar') to display on the right?

Answer (score 0):

After taking a little glance at your store and playing with the ccs. I think the structure of the tempalates and the css should be fixed.

You can try my little experiment with inspect element of browser: 
I add the css for the div id=container => width: 50%; float: left.
Then I change the css of div class=widget => float:left.

Woala the sidebar displayed on the right.

Of course the layout still a mess, this just to show you that the problem is within the design.

---

[enter link description here](http://dapur-uang.com)